# Haskell "Prelude.undefined" Error

Tags: haskell

I am fairly new to Haskell and I keep getting the following error, and I can't to figure out what is wrong (or even what it is trying to tell me). Any help would be appreciated!

*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at fileName.hs:35:12 in main:Main

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means you have used `undefined` in your file `fileName.hs` on line `35`. You will need to replace `undefined` with a real definition in order to run your code.

`undefined` is only used while you're sketching out definitions, and acts as a placeholder (that will always typecheck) until you have written your real code. If you try to evaluate it at runtime you will get an error, as you have found!